# No resource found that matches the given name (at 'headerLayout') in Xamarin.Android

Tags: c#, android, xml, xamarin

I'm creating Android app using Xamarin for Android. I want to use in my app NavigationDrawer, so I downloaded and installed 'Android Design Library' from Xamarin Components Store. Then I edited my layout for this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/drawerLayout"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

    <include
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        layout="@layout/toolbar" />
    <ListView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/articlesListView" />
    <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/navView"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/navHeader"
        app:menu="@menu/navMenu"/>
</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

navHeader.axml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="192dp"
    android:background="?attr/colorPrimaryDark"
    android:padding="16dp"
    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:gravity="bottom">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Username"
        android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Body1"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

and menu/navMenu.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
  <group android:checkableBehavior="single">
    <item
      android:id="@+id/nav_home"
      android:title="Home" />
    <item
      android:id="@+id/nav_messages"
      android:title="Messages" />
    <item
      android:id="@+id/nav_friends"
      android:title="Friends" />
    <item
      android:id="@+id/nav_discussion"
      android:title="Discussion" />
  </group>
  <item android:title="Sub items">
    <menu>
      <item
        android:title="Sub item 1" />
      <item
        android:title="Sub item 2" />
     </menu>
  </item>
</menu>
```

Unfortunately while compiling, I received following error:

> C:\Project\Project\File.axml: Error APT0000: No resource found that
>   matches the given name (at 'headerLayout' with value
>   '@layout/navHeader'). (APT0000) (AppName)
>   C:\Projects\Project\File.axml(0,0): Error APT0000: No resource found
>   that matches the given name (at 'menu' with value '@menu/navMenu').
>   (APT0000) (AppName)

Somebody knows how I may solved this problem?

Thank you in advance

Comment: Can you post the directory structure of your .axml files? All layouts should be in Resources/layout/ and menus should be in Resources/menu/

Comment: All layouts are in Resources/layout folder and navMenu.xml is in Resources/menu folder

Comment: I'm not certain of this, but I believe navMenu.xml should actually be navMenu.axml (I use .axml for all my menus) - can you rename and see if that fixes the problem?

Comment: Same issue, does anyone have an answer?

Answer (score 9):

I had the same issue.
I simply put lower case letters in the name of the header layout file and it worked.

Before (Failing with same error message):

```
app:headerLayout="@layout/DrawerHeader"
```

After:

```
app:headerLayout="@layout/drawerheader"
```

Comment: Doesn't work for me. seems like huge bug in Xamarin!

Answer (score 1):

Named Your layout file and menu with the small letter.

```
app:headerLayout="@layout/drawerheader"
app:menu="@menu/drawermenu"
```

Comment: This was my issue too. Uppercase names work for other resources, but not all of them I guess.

Answer (score 0):

Had the same problem. Guess it is a bug. C# code addition (in OnCreate() method of your activity) of navigation header view and menu view works fine for me. That is done with NavigationView methods [InflateMenu](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/NavigationView.html#inflateMenu(int)) and [inflateHeaderView](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/NavigationView.html#inflateHeaderView(int)).

**EDIT**

---

First delete

```
app:headerLayout="@layout/navHeader"
```

and

```
app:menu="@menu/navMenu"
```

from your Navigation Drawer layout and insert

```
navigationView = FindViewById<NavigationView>(Resource.Id.navView);    
navigationView.InflateHeaderView(Resource.Layout.navHeader);
navigationView.InflateMenu(Resource.Menu.navMenu);
```

somewhere in onCreate() method of your activity in question.